# flutter video_player Not playing the video in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-video-player

i use `video_palyer : ^2.1.0` the video playing normaly in debug mode but whene i run release apk the video not playing

**UPDATE**
the problem from `flutter_facebook_auth` and `flutter_facebook_login` whene i remove them the video work fine
is there any solution to keep both of them because i need both
`video_player` and `flutter_facebook_login` !

**voila my `flutter doctor :`**

> [√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.1.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.19042.867], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.1.0-12.1.pre at C:\src\flutter
> • Framework revision 8264cb3e8a (3 weeks ago), 2021-03-10 12:37:57 -0800
> • Engine revision 711ab3fda0
> • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-116.0.dev)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.3)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\DEVANDROID\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\DEVANDROID\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.20.0
>
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
> • EML L29 (mobile) • UBV7N18A12004906 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
> • Chrome (web)     • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.114
> • Edge (web)       • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.63
>
> • No issues found! Process finished with exit code 0

**and voila my code exemple :**

```
VideoPlayerController _controller;
  double width;
  double height;
  bool startedPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/video/successEqo.mp4');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  Future<bool> started() async {
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.setVolume(1);
    await _controller.initialize();
    await _controller.play();
    startedPlaying = true;
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: started(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == true) {
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: const Text('waiting for video to load'));
            }
          },
        )

        ,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try running following command:

```
flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add permissions to the AndroidManifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```